# Why JavaScript reduce method current index parameter starts from 1?

Tags: javascript

If you will launch this snipet it in your console

```
[0,1,2,3].reduce((acc, val, index) => {
  console.log(index);
  return acc;
});
```

You will get

```
1
2
3
```

So the question is why index starts from 1?

**UPD**: Probably I missing something very basic, but

```
[0,1,2,3].reduce((acc, val, index, initialValue) => {
  console.log(index);
  return acc;
});
```

gives me

```
1
2
3
0
```

**UPD2**: So yes, it's me missing something basic.

```
[0,1,2,3].reduce((acc, val, index) => {
  console.log(index);
  return acc;
}, 0);
```

Comment: Is it something obvious? Or what is the reason for downvote?

Comment: This is answered in the documentation on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):  "A value to use as the first argument to the first call of the callback. **If no initialValue is supplied, the first element in the array will be used and skipped.**"

Comment: @JaredSmith Yeah, missing something in the docs or assuming the worst in someone isn't a reason for a bad question imo

Comment: @bananabrann I'll restate the core of my objection: I realize this is something about which reasonable people could have different opinions. I disagree with yours, but I don't think it's **so** wrong that it's worth *calling you names in public over...* downvotes (to me at least) are not *personal*, the way, say, name-calling is.

Comment: @bananabrann You can disagree with people without calling them *petty*.

Comment: @Amy you probably won't believe me but before asking I was reading that doc. Sometimes it's just not obvious even if it is.

Comment: @VolodymyrI. It's not about that.

Comment: If you’re upset about the petty remark, that I’m sorry for. Though I still hold my original thinking, I did not mean an intentional attack of character

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you have not provided an `initialValue` argument. From the docs:

> If no `initialValue` is supplied, the first element in the array will be used and skipped

And reading further, there's a *direct* answer to your question:

> **Note:** If `initialValue` is not provided, `reduce()` will execute the callback function starting at index `1`, skipping the first index. If `initialValue` is provided, it will start at index `0`.

More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: I've updated my question, please can you explain my more on how can I make it start from 0 in my example?

Comment: `initialValue` is a *second* argument to the `reduce()` and not a fourth argument to the callback. Like this: `.reduce((acc, currentValue, index) => {...}, initialValue);`

Comment: @VolodymyrI. as a generally rule of thumb you almost *never* want to use an unseeded reduce (we all do it sometimes even though we shouldn't): it will throw on an empty array, it can make it hard to understand the code, etc.